# Understanding elb auto instance creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer

I am a begineer to aws elb. Can someone help me to understand how elb automatically creates a new instance depending on the traffic or cpu usage. Also when it creates a new instnces how does it copies code from existing instance?
Any link/article will also be appreciated.
Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How elb automatically creates a new instance depending on the traffic
>   or cpu usage?

ELB does not create the new instance the new instance is created by Launch configuration and Autoscaling group rules that you have set. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html

> Also when it creates a new instnces how does it copies code from
>   existing instance?

When a new instance gets created from the AMI you have to add the replication mechanism either using user data scripts (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) or running a cron job on that instance that will copy the files to that instance from a S3 bucket.

Comment: There's no requirement for storing your files on an S3 bucket. In fact you probably want to store your source code in a Git repository and have your script pull the code from there, not S3.

Comment: Yes so I mentioned User data script already and I did not say storing on S3 is mandatory.

Comment: The wording in your last sentence makes it sound like S3 would be the only possible place you could copy files from. I didn't want someone very new to AWS (like the OP) to be confused by that. A better wording would be something like: "... from an S3 bucket or a Git repository or other location."